# FlexSlider loop issue

Tags: jquery, html, carousel, flexslider

I've problem with flexSlider2 infinitive loop animation. 
I'm trying to make vertical carousel with 3 visible items:

[image: carousel]

The problem is when carousel reaches the last or first slide - first it clones item and replaces with correct one only after it slides into viewport. Is there any chance to make it clone correct item before it slides in viewport ?

I reproduced my problem in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jolanta/RLk8d/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="left-slider-content">
    <div class="flexslider-left carousel" id="flexslider-left">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/pmf1hghf3/slider_1.png?noCache=1392651530" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/u26xzbnlz/slider_2.png?noCache=1392651562" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s3.postimg.org/5yb8v5d4f/slider_3.png?noCache=1392651586" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/j7zbo5k37/slider_4.png?noCache=1392651603" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s12.postimg.org/p3rnfvc55/slider_5.png" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div class="sw_arrows"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-slider-content {
    width:100px;
}
.flexslider-left .flex-viewport {
    height: 297px!important;
}
.carousel .slides {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel .slides li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#flexslider-left').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  direction: "vertical",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: true,
  controlsContainer: ".sw_arrows",
  slideshow: false,
  move: 1,
});
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think you've violated the intention of the plugin by showing 3 items at a time. FlexSlider doesn't have that option in its api. Consider using BxSlider instead.

Comment: isherwood, thanks for your answer. I will try BxSlider :)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check Cycle2: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/
Based on my experience, it is by far the best jQuery carousel. It comes with a well defined API, can work with external plugins and provides number of different options for variety of manipulations.

Basic example for a vertical scroll, taken from Cycle2's site:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-fx="scrollVert"
    >
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

As long **jquery.cycle2.js** is added to the HEAD section the above would work without additional initialization.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/natnaydenova/7uXPx/